# Using PDFbox to create PDF referencing OTF fonts

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, embedded-fonts

Good morning!

I have a newbie PDFbox question which I'm hoping for some help with ...

I've just (last week) downloaded the latest PDFbox source from github and am trying to create a HelloWorldOTF.java, based on the HelloWorldTTF.java example, with the hope of creating a PDF file which uses an OTF font (in this case, Adobe Caslon Pro Regular) to add text to the output PDF.

Here's what I have so far:

```
        doc = new PDDocument();

        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);

        String testOtfFontFile =  "c:/windows/fonts/ACaslonPro-Regular.otf";
        String testTtfFontFile = "c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf";
        String testPdfFile = "c:/tmp/pdfboxtest.pdf";

        CFFFont font = loadCFFFont(testOtfFontFile);

        PDFont ttfFont = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, new File(testTtfFontFile));

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc,
                page);
        contentStream.beginText();
        // How to set the CFFFont?
        contentStream.setFont(ttfFont, 12);
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
        contentStream.drawString(text);
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();
        doc.save(testPdfFile);
        System.out.println(testPdfFile + " created!");
```

I can load a CFFFont using this code: (loadCFFFont()):

```
            CFFFont cff = null;
            input = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
            CFFParser cffParser = new CFFParser();
            cff = cffParser.parse(bytes).get(0);
```

... but can't for the life of me figure out how to get from a CFFFont to a PDFont in order to be able to use it to set the font via setFont().

Any help or pointers would be hugely appreciated ...

Thanks a million for reading this far ;)

Comment: I doubt that it will work... I've only seen examples of writing of PDFs with TT fonts. The class you're mentioning is being used for rendering. If you don't get an answer here, I suggest asking on the user list, and if you get no or a negative answer, open an enhancement request in PDFBox JIRA. Alternatively, try iText. (I can't believe I'm writing this. Come back to PDFBox once we support writing with CFFFonts :-))

Comment: Hey Tilman - thank you so much for your response; I had already tried the user list but to no avail, so it looks like the next step is to open an enhancement request ... that way I might be able to avoid iText altogether ;)

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me by referring [to this link.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2482)

Using OTFParser  to covert otf to ttf.

```
OTFParser otfParser = new OTFParser();
OpenTypeFont otf = otfParser.parse(new File("C:/Users/beder/Downloads/code/CODE Light.otf"));

PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, otf, false);
```

Comment: Please also read the comments to [PDFBOX-2482](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2482) after Benjamin Eder proposed that approach. Apparently the result is not completely conform to PDF specifications.